# Increment values in a column based on another column (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, increment

I have `DataFrame` containing three columns:

1. The incrementor
2. The incremented
3. Other

I would like lengthen the DataFrame in a particular way. In each row, I want to add a number of rows, depending on the incrementor, and in these rows we increment the incremented, while the "other" is just replicated.

I made a small example which makes it more clear:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,3], [5,20,0], ['a','b','c']]).transpose()
df.columns = ['incrementor', 'incremented', 'other']

df
  incrementor incremented other
0           2           5     a
1           1          20     b
2           3           0     c
```

The desired output is:

```
  incrementor incremented other
0           2           5     a
1           2           6     a
2           1           20    b
3           3           0     c
4           3           1     c
5           3           2     c
```

Is there a way to do this elegantly and efficiently with Pandas? Or is there no way to avoid looping?

Comment: Okay, could you walk through it step-by-step? I'm not sure what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get repeated rows on `incrementor` using `repeat` and `.loc`

```
In [1029]: dff = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.incrementor.astype(int))]
```

Then, modify `incremented` with `cumcount`

```
In [1030]: dff.assign(
              incremented=dff.incremented + dff.groupby(level=0).incremented.cumcount()
              ).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[1030]:
  incrementor incremented other
0           2           5     a
1           2           6     a
2           1          20     b
3           3           0     c
4           3           1     c
5           3           2     c
```

---

Details

```
In [1031]: dff
Out[1031]:
  incrementor incremented other
0           2           5     a
0           2           5     a
1           1          20     b
2           3           0     c
2           3           0     c
2           3           0     c

In [1032]: dff.groupby(level=0).incremented.cumcount()
Out[1032]:
0    0
0    1
1    0
2    0
2    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```